# Qliksense rest connection to connect neo4j sandbox

Tags: rest, neo4j, qliksense

I am trying to connect to NEO4j data base using qliksense through REST API connection but I am unable to understand how to get the API end point and pass the cypher query. Could anybody please guide me or share the poc if you have.

I am trying to load node data created in the neo4j sandbox by firing cypher query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pull your Neo4j data into Qlik Sense, whether cloud or on-prem, you will need to use the [Neo4j Connector for BI ODBC driver](https://neo4j.com/bi-connector/?version=1.1.0&flavour=windows) in order to get that data. The ODBC driver is what allows Qlik to pull that Neo4j data without a native data connector and without any RESTful option in your case.

If you use Qlik Sense Enterprise on Windows ("on-prem") then you will need to install and configure this driver on **all servers where the Qlik Engine is installed**.

If you use Qlik Sense Enterprise SaaS ("Cloud"), then you will need to install and use this Neo4j driver on your org's own Windows server, whether that's in cloud/VPC or on-prem. That server will ultimately need to have [Qlik DataTransfer](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/QlikDataTransfer/install-Qlik-DataTransfer.htm) installed on it, as well, as that is the tool that is used to get the data from the ODBC driver and then up to your Qlik cloud tenant.

The setup is easy though:

1. Use [this link](https://neo4j.com/bi-connector/?version=1.1.0&flavour=windows) to choose and download the Neo4j ODBC driver version for your Windows server (server where Qlik Sense Engine Service is installed / where Qlik DataTransfer is or will be installed).
2. Unzip the downloaded ZIP file and then run the installer for the correct bit version, usually 64-bit.
3. Once that is installed, open the **ODBC Data Sources (64)** program on your server and then add a new **System DSN** source (unless there's already a newly-created **Simba Neo4j** connection there, in that case just double click on that).
4. The `Host` parameter should be your Bolt URL without the protocol or port (for example, just `0.00.000.000`). you hopefully know your `Port` number, that's 7687 by default. You can leave the `Database` parameter blank if you want to. Then put in your credentials and click the **Test...** button. If that works, click the **OK** button and then close the ODBC program.
5. If you are using Qlik Sense on-prem, [create a new ODBC connection](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/May2023/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/DataSource/ODBC.htm). If you're on Qlik SaaS then open up the Qlik DataTransfer GUI, go to the **Connection details** tab, and then click the green **Add** button.
6. Choose the **ODBC** option, choose **System DSN**, then select your new Neo4j option. Then click the green **Create** button.

[image: Screenshot of Qlik DataTransfer connection create screen]

7. Now go to the **Data connections** tab and select the green **Add** button. Put in your desired options and then click the **Next** button.

[image: Screenshot of Qlik DataTransfer data connection create screen]

8. Choose your new ODBC connection. Then, select the database from the dropdown. From the **Owner** dropdown, choose either `Node` or `Relationship`. Then put a checkmark next to all of the tables you want based on the selected type. Finally, click the green **Next** button.

[image: Screenshot of Qlik DataTransfer table selection screen]

9. Optionally, choose the app(s) that you want to be automatically reloaded whenever this Neo4j data is uploaded to Qlik Cloud.
10. When you're ready, go ahead and select your new data connection and then click the **Upload** button.

[image: Screenshot of Qlik DataTransfer data upload screen]

11. You should hopefully get a successful result!

[image: Screenshot of Qlik DataTransfer successful data upload message]

12. Go to your Qlik tenant and find your Neo4j data, uploaded as QVD files:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik SaaS data files]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explination, could you please let me know if i can fire cypher query using ODBC connector. Also, do you know any extension which handle more nodes to diplay network graph

Comment: It appears that the BI connector only allows SQL queries, as it is specifically addressing the need for pulling in Neo4j data into more "traditional" SQL BI workflows/tools. The [Neo4j JDBC connector](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc) exists but Qlik Sense is not Java based, so there's no native way to use that driver. You would have to find a tool that can bridge JDBC to ODBC but even then, it would be a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible out of the box.
Sandbox exposes connections via [Bolt only](https://neo4j.com/docs/bolt/current/bolt/), not Neo4j's REST API.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/

Note that the HTTP API is not yet available with the cloud version of Aura

As already mentioned, you can't use HTTP API with the sandbox.

Using the neo4j docker container or neo4j desktop might be the path of least resistance for trying out the HTTP API.   I'd also consider using tools like https://www.postman.com/ or https://insomnia.rest/ as they make testing with the HTTP API really easy and then move onto qliksense

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this was really helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).